# How to transform 2D matrix into a 3D matrix by adding a constant time dimension?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 2-D matrix `512 x 512` for spatial dimensions, how can I construct a 3-D matrix by adding a constant time dimension? I want to use a FFT transform on it with time direction to prove that there is only DC.

I have tried following code:

```
data3D(:, :, 1) = data;         % data has already load from the above.
im3 = abs(ifft(data3D, [], 3)); % use ifft to the 3rd direction.
imshow(im3);                    % to show the image from the ifft.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your third dimension (time) to be constant, all you need is to `repmat` along this dimension

```
data3D = repmat( data2D, [1, 1, T] ); % create T replicates along time
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Excuse me for troubling you again. I want to check if I have to replace T to some constant number(1,2,for instance),because when I define the data3D as the above, matlab warning me of "Undefined function or variable 'T'."

Comment: @mark you are correct you should define `T` as the number of time steps you want to have. `T=2` is a valid settings

Comment: Thanks again. But as I see,you might use repmat in a wrong way. For when I type "help repmat",there only some ways to use it as follows:
B = repmat(A,M,N);
B = repmat(A,[M N]);
B = repmat(A,[M N P ...]) ;

Answer (score 0):

For more generic purposes, you can make your temporal vector lay on the third dimension, for example:

```
t = linspace(0, 1, 100);
T = reshape(t, [1 1 length(t)];
```

And do your computations in general with `bsxfun`, for example, if your spatial matrix `A` contains the phasors of some harmonic analysis, let it evolve with time:

```
s = real(bsxfun(@times, A, exp(1i*omega*T)));
```

Then Fourier transform it along the temporal dimension

```
S = fft(s, [], 3);
```

To make the problem invariant to the number of spatial dimensions (2D, 3D), I would put all spatial dimensions along one vertical vector and the time dimension along a horizontal one, and perform my logic with 2D matrices

```
A_ = A(:)
t = linspace(0, 1, 100);
s = real(bsxfun(@times, A_, exp(1i*omega*t)))
S = fft(s, [], 2);
```

And you can always go back to your original 2D (or 3D) arrangement with `reshape`

```
S_2D = reshape(S, [size(A,1) size(A,2) length(t)]);
```